# Using curl with certificate that has no password

Tags: ssl, curl

I have my own CA and client certificate that I have been using successfully with cURL using the normal format:

```
curl --cacert /etc/myca.crt --cert /etc/myclient.pem:mypassword --cert-type PEM --get https://myhost.com
```

Now, for reasons outside the scope of this question, I have the same client certificate but the password has been removed using openssl. Using openssl I have verified that the new certificate is correct and I can use it to make SSL connections using applications other than cURL, but I cannot get it to work with cURL.

If I don't enter a password:

```
curl --cacert /etc/myca.crt --cert /etc/myclient.pem --cert-type PEM --get https://example.com
```

I get an error saying "curl: (58) unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)"

I have also tried:

```
curl --cacert /etc/myca.crt --cert /etc/myclient.pem: --cert-type PEM --get https://example.com
```

but I get the same error.

I am making the call to cURL from within a Perl script, so I need to find a way that will not prompt me for the password. I am using cURL 7.15.5 on RHEL 5.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of the `--pass` switch:

```
--pass <phrase>                  (SSL/SSH) Passphrase for the private key
```

To pass an empty passphrase you can use:

```
--pass ''
```